# java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "cmd.exe": error=2, No such file or directory when executing a command in java docker container

Tags: java, docker, cmd, processbuilder

I need to run a java script in a java docker container. This java code uses ProcessBuilder to run a command. When executing the container I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "cmd.exe": error=2, 
No such file or directory
        at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1143)
        at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1073)
        at test.main(test.java:39)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
        at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.forkAndExec(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:314)
        at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:244)
        at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1110)
        at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1073)
        at test.main(test.java:39)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.launcher.Main.execute(Main.java:419)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:192)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:132)
```

The code producing the error is the following:

```
        String [] test = {"cmd.exe", "/c", "cd \"/d D:\\4.12.0.0\\my_Software\\Startscripts\\Windows \" && pscconverter single C:\\Users\\Kuehnel\\Documents\\Projekte\\S2_Deployment_PipeLine\\Test_cmd_line D:\\target"}; 
        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(test);
        builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
        Process p = builder.start();
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while (true) {
            line = r.readLine();
            System.out.println(line);
            if (line == null) {break;}
        }
```

I use a custom tool that converts the content of a folder into a psc file. For this I first access the folder where the pscconverter.cmd file is located and then I execute it with the required input parameters. First the mode "single" following two paths for input and output folder.

Is it possible to access runtime in a Docker container?

Comment: I assume that you are running in a docker Windows container.  Correct?

Comment: yes I am using windows

Comment: I *think* ProcessBuilder does not use the `PATH` environment variable to lookup the executable. Try using `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe` as first argument. (Remember to escape the backslashes by doubling them, i.e. "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe").

Comment: @Christian.K This does not work either. I am getting the same error just with the modified parameter.